# gzip unix command with tar command

Tags: unix, gzip

I want to zip more than one file using gzip, but when I unzip it I should get multiple files.

I tried tar with zip but tar created extra folders that I don't want.

The files I want to zip are `cp1.txt, cp2.txt, cp3.txt`.

After unzipping the files should be `cp1.txt, cp2.txt, cp3.txt`

But using the tar command with gzip it is creating files like

```
/bbpre/spool/COPY/ZIP/cp1.txt,cp2.txt,cp3.txt
```

I don't want `/bbpre/spool/COPY/ZIP/` I only want the files.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the commands you are using to zip and unzip the files?

Comment: Ugh.  I loathe the terminology being used here.  You don't zip files with gzip.  You gzip files with gzip.  If you're zipping files, you do so with a command such as the "zip" command (which typically refers to Info-Zip), or maybe another command (like 7za).  gzip only handles one file per .gz archive.  The workaround to that limitation is to use another format to archive multiple files and then have gzip compress that archive.  In Unix (I note that this question has the Unix tag), the most traditional format to use for that task is tar.

Answer (score 1):

By tar during extraction you can strip-off the first n leading components of the filename/path.

In your case if you have done a tar from files:

```
/bbpre/spool/COPY/ZIP/cp1.txt  
/bbpre/spool/COPY/ZIP/cp2.txt
/bbpre/spool/COPY/ZIP/cp3.txt
```

by extract with `strip-components` flag you can remove unwanted path filename levels:

```
tar -xvzf yourtar.tar --strip-components=4
```

will remove the `/bbpre/spool/COPY/ZIP` and will put `cp1.txt, cp2.txt, cp3.txt` in the current working directory.

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to take multiple files and zip them at once and then unzip them back into multiple files at once. Here is how to do this:

```
$ touch 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
$ gzip 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
$ gzip -d 1.txt.gz 2.txt.gz 3.txt.gz
```

I just tried this in a VM and it created 3 files, gzipped them separately, and then unzipped them separately.

Comment: below command making separate zip files i want one zip file and when i will unzip i want it separate files $ gzip 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt

Comment: Yes, that is what my post advised. Did this work for you?

Comment: no my requirement is create one zip file for all files and when i will unzip it i should get all files

Comment: So you want to zip a directory with arbitrary files inside and then when you unzip have those files again?

Comment: No i want to zip 3 files in one zip file and when i will unzip it 3 files should come.if i am using gzip it is concatenating all 3 files.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot make a directory, place the files in said directory, and then zip the directory?

Comment: see like in windows if you will zip files it will create one zip and in time of unzip it will give separate files that i want in unix

Comment: Try this, make a directory using mkdir, then copy your files to it using cp, and finally tar -xcvf name_of_archive name_of_directory. This should do exactly what you want. To unzip tar -zxvf name_of_archive.